# Design pattern to apply a set of operations on an object

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I'm looking for a specific design pattern that is used to implement function composition.  The goal is to be able to pass an object that represents a set of operations applied on a specific sequence to a client, and let the client apply the operations without caring what they might be. The pattern covers the following requirements:

1. needs to apply an operation to an input (i.e., maps a given input to an output)
2. operations must be composable
3. each operation can be applied in isolation or composed with other operations

Requirement #1 sounds like a strategy pattern or command pattern, while requirement #2 brings the composite design pattern to mind.

Does anyone know if there's a OO design pattern that fits these requirements?

Comment: Chain of responsability plus composite?

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for `monoids` http://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/10/06/monoids/

Comment: Also, do you need to work in a specific language?

Comment: If you need to treat operations as data, and compose them, there is also the Command pattern in OOP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Comment: @JamesFaix I'm working with C++ but I was hoping that this use case was already covered by a specific OOP design pattern.